# Undefined Type error using willvincent/feeds

Tags: php, laravel, rss, feed

I'm getting the following error:

```
[{
    "resource": ".../app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "1009",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined type 'Feeds'.",
    "source": "intelephense",
    "startLineNumber": 60,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 60,
    "endColumn": 23
}]
```

I know the code might be a bit messy, i'm trying to learn the way it works by just start doing it!
I brought the facades into scope with a use [facadeName] declaration in my HomeController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\View\Composers\ProfileComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use willvincent\Feeds;
```

I tried every declaration that willvincent\feeds has to offer, but non of them worked.

The controller part that is requesting it is also in the HomeController.php:

```
    public function feedreader() {
        
        $feed = \Feeds::make('http://blog.case.edu/news/feed.atom');
        $data = array(
          'title'     => $feed->get_title(),
          'permalink' => $feed->get_permalink(),
          'items'     => $feed->get_items(),
        );
    
        return View::make('feed', $data);
      }
```

Comment: Using `\Feeds` in your code will never work, unless `Feeds` is a Laravel Alias and the package knows it. Use the full namespace to the package! Did you follow the usage section on the package's github page? Did you put the service provider?

Comment: So instead of using \Feeds::make or Feeds::make

I would have to use:
willvincent\Feeds\Facades\Feeds::make

Comment: I checked the package through the phone, and you can use `\Feeds` ONLY if you have the service provider being loaded, else use the full namespace as you wrote here in the comments